# Typescript - Type a function that accepts an array, alters one of its properties, but still returns the same typed array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have form fields represented as objects that get mapped over and based upon the `type` returns React elements:

```js
import { FieldProps } from "~types";

const fields: FieldProps[] = [
  { type: "text", name: "username", value: "", required: true, ...other props },
  { type: "password", name: "password", value: "", required: true, ...other props },
  ...etc
]

export default fields;
```

The problem I'm running into is I'm trying to validate the fields after a form is submitted and check for any errors in `value`:

```js
 handleSubmit = (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { validatedFields, errors } = fieldValidator(this.state.fields);

    if(errors) {
      this.setState({ errors });
      return;
    }

    ...etc
 }
```

but this reusable validate function has a ts error:

```js
import isEmpty from "lodash.isempty";

/**
 * Helper function to validate form fields.
 *
 * @function
 * @param {array} fields - an array containing form fields.
 * @returns {object} validated/updated fields and number of errors.
 * @throws {error}
 */

const fieldValidator = <
 T extends Array<{ type: string; value: string; required?: boolean }>
>(
  fields: T,
): { validatedFields: T; errors: number } => {
  try {
    if (isEmpty(fields)) throw new Error("You must supply an array of form fields to validate!");
    let errorCount: number = 0;

    // this turns the "validatedFields" array into an { errors: string; type: string; name: 
    // string; value: string; required?: boolean | undefined;}[] type, when it needs to be "T", 
    // but "T" won't be inferred as an Array with Object props: type, value, required, value defined within it
    const validatedFields = fields.map(field => {
      let errors = "";
      const { type, value, required } = field;
      if ((!value && required) || (isEmpty(value) && required)) {
        errors = "Required.";
      } else if (
        type === "email" &&
        !/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(field.value)
      ) {
        errors = "Invalid email.";
      }

      if (errors) errorCount += 1;

      return { ...field, errors };
    });

    return { validatedFields, errors: errorCount }; // TS error here
  } catch (err) {
    throw String(err);
  }
};

export default fieldValidator;
```

Since `validatedFields` turns into:

```
{
    errors: string;
    name: string;
    value: string;
    type: string;
    required: boolean;
}[]
```

and it's returned `{ validatedFields, errors }`, it throws this TS error:

```
Type '{ errors: string; type: string; value: string; required?: boolean | undefined; }[]' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  '{ errors: string; type: string; value: string; required?: boolean | undefined; }[]' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{ type: string; value: string; required?: boolean | undefined; }[]'.ts(2322)
index.ts(17, 6): The expected type comes from property 'validatedFields' which is declared here on type '{ validatedFields: T; errors: number; }'
```

Is there a way to infer `T` as an array of objects that expects at least 4 (or more) properties, but returns the same typed array (just with an updated `errors` property)?

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglhANgEwAoCcD2YDOUC8UA3gFBRQDGiAhjjgHLUC2EA-AFxQ7DpwB2AcwA0ZKMjg5qAI0QRkHKFMyZZ1PiPIR0WdDgXdegjVDA0KEABYrkW-T37DRNKUk4GHxgPSeomPgGELNQE2TgAKCE4AJQhqCmAAOkDgiABRADcIPmAAHjUQAD4ASgICqHTMOGQAblE%20ZkiueyNRUEg3ZsdydFjkAHk%20RBAFJRVY9VEegEcAVzge5E5R1QnydOpEGcb3QVFuEFk9TkwpACsIeJIAX1qSEgo-bigAMwQUHE54JDQsXABtAC6BCgf1ERCgonIbUaACJgBAAB7AGFCCHkcjOVxQGEAVRwWnqLBRaPRhNhM3x6DJxMhUC0Og%202JRtPWm1hNPRUGmcwWnB4W2MV2M4NpVFoDAanBhiOYpggzM50KlYHFAHdMOhkBz0ZjEOwYahxZhVZrteQycq1RqtajafSNYyYWbyhstlLndz5nI%20egBSTyPtDpxwaqqsALFKAIwAVgADGAETCoELRFcSADbg8%20E9Xt8AGobKrUYAa4E5UQAFTpSKyyDwAEFtNQQDlwUqmoYBNUXWyOp3u56FiNlCtkwUSAUwqJc%209OBWREVgz2i-DkF9Z1AK937bpOHwZkwXOhk6ViK10CAz5y4M8oGEAIQzutQAA%20L5ebzrCVkgnDUByUCxiU4ZYKqUB8BAYGpNoGphDCACamAzFATAUsAXAzGApiXmoUDUE2l6YLeT44PeMJFLUnKyOhO7%20Eh2R7geR7ArGtyclmTysiucjrs%20hAkQkTDUGAYRPqepCchiEA0TBujAk6lGSRx6FtuAECoqyfqDnIJ78Z%20inXreYQPpp0AAGRmVyECzF6yAlG%20d5hKZUAWT2WzflkAh-gBQEuZZ2l2SUEmSZosl4IQMIxDZCwJDCBnolcdKIPiUA3netKKmpBD4BFEBCXAiBJhZGXovengAHp-PWAC0ABasbVQAnAkAD6ACkADU1UAh1AACVV1Q1zXdR1AA6CQDbVAJEAATEIAAsVwACSeHACTwtwomfgkplFCVQUlaFDLyQAknwXHIHS%20WILF8XkGmJVpREYUlLR9HoR1hCRmxkk9MAMxUsQUAJCDT6ojueA3LSVwUXcnJ-QDfBAxdxY8Z%20ODg2FnBvTM2TJopiUUMWFAWHe9IHYqFigVAADKnTPegsP3dcmaPCpy7IKja7o5jx2JXp%20aFpzJboFt3w4HtHFjN%20mACE5Qtc7xEv3I80uILLDMOhRQA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out by extending `T` to `any[]` and then defining the result of `validatedFields as T` to preserve the passed in types:

```js
const fieldValidator = <
  T extends any[]
>(
  fields: T,
): { validatedFields: T; errors: number } => {
  try {
    if (!fields || fields.length < 0) throw new Error("You must supply an array of fields!");
    let errorCount: number = 0;

    const validatedFields = fields.map(field => {
      let errors = "";
      const { type, value, required }: Pick<BaseFieldProps, "type" | "value" | "required"> = field;
      if ((!value && required) || ((value && value.length < 0) && required)) {
        errors = "Required.";
      } else if (
        type === "email" &&
        !/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(value)
      ) {
        errors = "Invalid email.";
      } 

      if (errors) errorCount += 1;

      return { ...field, errors };
    }) as T;

    return { validatedFields, errors: errorCount };
  } catch (err) {
    throw String(err);
  }
};
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-Wq5RdBgSBQM5rnSgmspkKQ5BRuNqAYMuIMM2qbmOAAeoyACCAC0ABac4iwAnFEAD6ACkADUIvMorAACwvi5LMsq4rAA6USa2LzIUFifAACzlAAJI4qBRLUHBTXyUQ7dkPM4zztDNSQrMAJJ0E6xRdOzGCk+THFSjzdPBIlCC5M1rUaCkUCK+QU69XNBjABo+pYVE+eeSq3sruT5S5IgUASRn7wQNnueSoHWDCUNe5F7HbAJ213LlKtlPhMJ4SeK5NoewmLHFlAP6vDHeB1WuCJcf1DeCU3ekGWw9RTm3JldFO1lfXyAk6av6ZO-5bvcQcgUEDwgQAAYADIanmUBWxQm+MnOzKBc-5R3xfdIr4YBvvfBKO834QCnH-OeHIl4DVXi3fyG8zb4ztBAHElMD78RXsJU+VUsQAO3EAkBd8-wUm5ORWk242Bv3qFiT+39SKULpNA2BRCbDX1vnfMBEFX4UHQdAkoQA)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are searching for ?

```
type EssentialField = { type: string; value: string; required?: boolean }[];
```

Typescript use duck typing.

```
type FieldProps = {
  className?: string,
  disabled?: boolean,
  errors?: string,
  placeholder?: string,
  label: string,
  // onChange?: (e: React.ChangeEvent<any>) => void;
  name: string,
  type: string,
  readOnly?: boolean,
  required: boolean,
  value: string
  styles?: object
};


const fields: FieldProps[] = [
  { 
    type: "text", 
    label: "Username", 
    name: "username", 
    errors: "",
    value: "", 
    required: true,
  },
  { 
    className: "example",
    type: "password", 
    label:"Passowrd", 
    name: "password", 
    errors: "", 
    value: "", 
    required: true, 
    styles: { width: "150px" },
  }
];

type EssentialField = { type: string; value: string; required?: boolean }[];

const fieldValidator = (
  fields: EssentialField,
): { validatedFields: EssentialField; errors: number } => {
  try {
    if (!fields || fields.length < 0) throw new Error("You must supply an array of fields!");
    let errorCount: number = 0;

    const validatedFields = fields.map(field => {
      let errors = "";
      const { type, value, required } = field;
      if ((!value && required) || ((value && value.length < 0) && required)) {
        errors = "Required.";
      } else if (
        type === "email" &&
        !/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(field.value)
      ) {
        errors = "Invalid email.";
      }

      if (errors) errorCount += 1;

      return { ...field, errors };
    });

    return { validatedFields, errors: errorCount };
  } catch (err) {
    throw String(err);
  }
};

const { validatedFields, errors } = fieldValidator(fields)
console.log(validatedFields)
console.log(errors);
```

This remove the error, without usage of `as any` or other tricks.

EDIT: Maybe you want something like that:

```
type EssentialField = ({ type: string; value: string; required?: boolean }&{[key: string]: any})[];

// this allow you to do:
validatedFields[0].placeholder; // ...
// or
validatedFields[0].someUnknowProperty; // ...
```

This is intersecting the type with an associative array (`{[key: string]: any})`). Usually accessed like that `associativeArray['someKey']`, but it can also be used like that `associativeArray.someKey`.

The benefit is that your IDE should propose you the `type` and `required` field in auto-completion.

Comment: It's close, but neither of the solutions above preserve other types located within `FieldProps[]`. For example, `validatedFields[0].label` (which is required, see Typescript playground) is not typed nor provided within auto-complete after validation.